# How to get results from subprocess stdout and display them realtime in TextCtrl? (Python 2.7 - wxPython)

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, wxpython

I am creating a GUI using wxPython. And I am trying to display results from subprocess.Popen to TextCtrl one line at a time. Since there is a huge chunk of information, the window undergoes a NOT RESPONDING phase before displaying everything altogether. I am also using threads. 
I have tried poll, read(), readline(), itr and still the output gets displayed all at once instead of line by line after the window's brief NOT RESPONDING phase. It would be great if someone could help me with this problem. Thanks!

Comment: As we have no idea what it is that you are doing please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running `subprocess` in a thread, then you just need to pass a reference to your text control to that thread and then call the text control's `write` method using one of wxPython's thread-safe methods, such as `wx.CallAfter`. Here's a fairly simple example:

```
import subprocess
import time
import wx

from threading import Thread


class PingThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, text_ctrl):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.text_ctrl = text_ctrl
        self.sentinel = True
        self.start()

    def run(self):            
        proc = subprocess.Popen("ping www.google.com",
                                     shell=True,
                                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        while self.sentinel:
            line = proc.stdout.readline()
            if line.strip() == "":
                pass
            else:
                wx.CallAfter(self.text_ctrl.write, line)

            if not line: break

        proc.kill()


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Redirecter')
        self.ping_thread = None

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.log = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        ping_btn = wx.Button(panel, label='Ping')
        ping_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_ping)

        main_sizer.Add(self.log, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        main_sizer.Add(ping_btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(main_sizer)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.on_close)

        self.Show()

    def on_ping(self, event):
        self.ping_thread = PingThread(self.log)

    def on_close(self, event):
        if self.ping_thread:
            self.ping_thread.sentinel = False
            self.ping_thread.join()
        self.Destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You can read more about wxPython and threads at the following links:

- https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/
- https://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

Comment: This is great example @MikeDriscoll. The Not Responding issue is resolved :D. I was wondering if there is a way to display stdout realtime?

Comment: This is going to be really close to real time as it is. Is there some reason you would need it to be faster than this?

Comment: For some reason it still shows everything all at once after a long wait. I just want the user to be able to see the output real time as it is a long process and don't want them to think that nothing is running. This is the only reason I want it real time. Also, thank you so much for helping me with the same! :)

Comment: Does my example work on you machine in real time? I wonder if the process you are running doesn't output a line at a time. You could try reading a specific amount of bytes and sending them to the text control.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice! It finally worked when I did python -u ____ :D